# SpringBoot 2 with oAuth redirection issue

Tags: spring-boot, spring-oauth2

I am trying to authenticate and auth via internal company auth server.

getting the following error with ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS and HTTP 302

````
2019-09-18 09:23:54.310 TRACE 8 --- [qtp254692047-20] s.n.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection  : KeepAlive stream retrieved from the cache, sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient(https://privateURL/tokeninfo)
2019-09-18 09:23:54.310 TRACE 8 --- [qtp254692047-20] s.n.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection  : Proxy used: DIRECT
2019-09-18 09:23:54.310 DEBUG 8 --- [qtp254692047-20] s.n.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection  : sun.net.www.MessageHeader@3b6fad4e6 pairs: {GET /oauth2/tokeninfo HTTP/1.1: null}{Authorization: Bearer eyJraWQiOi####}{Accept: application/json, application/*+json}{User-Agent: Java/11.0.4}{Host: privateURL.com}{Connection: keep-alive}
2019-09-18 09:23:54.315 DEBUG 8 --- [qtp254692047-20] s.n.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection  : sun.net.www.MessageHeader@56d0f8f314 pairs: {null: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized}{Date: Wed, 18 Sep 2019 09:23:54 GMT}{Content-Type: application/problem+json}{Transfer-Encoding: chunked}{Connection: keep-alive}{Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate}{Expires: 0}{Pragma: no-cache}{Server: unspecified}{Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains}{X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff}{X-Flow-Id: RiNj7zF0fq3MWJBePUzlkA}{X-Frame-Options: DENY}{X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block}
2019-09-18 09:23:54.316 DEBUG 8 --- [qtp254692047-20] s.n.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection  : Server Authentication for AuthenticationHeader: prefer null returned null
2019-09-18 09:23:54.316 DEBUG 8 --- [qtp254692047-20] org.springframework.web.HttpLogging      : Response 401 UNAUTHORIZED
2019-09-18 09:23:54.317 DEBUG 8 --- [qtp254692047-20] o.s.w.c.HttpMessageConverterExtractor    : Reading to [org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.OAuth2Exception]
2019-09-18 09:23:54.318  WARN 8 --- [qtp254692047-20] o.s.b.a.s.o.r.UserInfoTokenServices      : Could not fetch user details: class org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Unauthorized, 401 Unauthorized
2019-09-18 09:23:54.318 DEBUG 8 --- [qtp254692047-20] o.s.b.a.s.o.r.UserInfoTokenServices      : userinfo returned error: Could not fetch user details
...
2019-09-18 09:23:54.229 DEBUG 8 --- [qtp254692047-18] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=2019-09-18T09:23:54.229553Z, principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={details=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 99.99.99.99; SessionId: xxx, type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]
...
ttp_server_requests_seconds{exception="None",method="GET",outcome="REDIRECTION",status="302",uri="REDIRECTION",quantile="0.5",} 0.011534336
http_server_requests_seconds{exception="None",method="GET",outcome="REDIRECTION",status="302",uri="REDIRECTION",quantile="0.75",} 0.014680064
http_server_requests_seconds{exception="None",method="GET",outcome="REDIRECTION",status="302",uri="REDIRECTION",quantile="0.95",} 0.047710208
http_server_requests_seconds{exception="None",method="GET",outcome="REDIRECTION",status="302",uri="REDIRECTION",quantile="0.99",} 0.536346624
http_server_requests_seconds_count{exception="None",method="GET",outcome="REDIRECTION",status="302",uri="REDIRECTION",} 14.0
http_server_requests_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="GET",outcome="REDIRECTION",status="302",uri="REDIRECTION",} 0.719216709```

Any pointers on what could be the problem here ?
````

Comment: I think it is self explainatory`ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

Comment: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS is the symptom , what could be the cause ?

Comment: Its written in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error occures when browser get redirection request, commence it and as a result another redirect request is sent to the browser (most commonly the exact same one)

Simply speaking, browser is caught in infinite redirection loop.

Most probably, after you hit secured endpoint, instead of being redirected to UNSECURED endpoint that allows user to authenticate itself, redirection goes to another secured endpoint - and loop closes

Comment: @AbhishekAsh UNSECURED endpoint in above context is something like login page which doesn't need user to be already authenticated.